My python program isn't identifying the columns in my large CSV File
I am currently creating a Python program to compare the historical data price of a stock to the predicted price through the Black-Merton-Scholes equation. Right now I am utilizing a large csv dataset from Kaggle (I am using the 2021 to 2023 data). But every time I try to run my program I get a KeyError.
from math import log, sqrt, exp
from mibian import BS
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

historical_data = pd.read_csv('historical_data.csv')

underlying_price = historical_data['UNDERLYING_LAST']
strike_price = historical_data['STRIKE']
time_to_expiration = historical_data['DTE'] / 365.0
risk_free_rate = 0.05
volatility = historical_data['C_IV'] / 100.0

def black_scholes(price, strike, time, rate, volatility):
    call_option = BS([price, strike, rate, time], volatility=volatility)
    return call_option.callPrice

theoretical_prices = [black_scholes(price, strike, time, risk_free_rate, volatility)
                      for price, strike, time in zip(underlying_price, strike_price, time_to_expiration)]
market_prices = historical_data['C_LAST']

mse = mean_squared_error(market_prices, theoretical_prices)

plt.plot(historical_data['QUOTE_DATE'], market_prices, label='Market Price')
plt.plot(historical_data['QUOTE_DATE'], theoretical_prices, label='Theoretical Price')
plt.xlabel('Date')
plt.ylabel('Option Price')
plt.title('Black-Scholes Model Performance - Call Option for Apple')
plt.legend()
plt.show()

Here is the error given:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/shashishmac/PythonProjects/GTBS/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 3805, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
  File "index.pyx", line 167, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "index.pyx", line 196, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 7081, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 7089, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: 'UNDERLYING_LAST'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/shashishmac/PythonProjects/GTBS/main.py", line 48, in <module>
    underlying_price = historical_data['UNDERLYING_LAST']
  File "/Users/shashishmac/PythonProjects/GTBS/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 4102, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
  File "/Users/shashishmac/PythonProjects/GTBS/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 3812, in get_loc
    raise KeyError(key) from err
KeyError: 'UNDERLYING_LAST'



Take a closer look at the first row of the csv. The column names actually have brackets like [QUOTE_UNIXTIME], [QUOTE_READTIME].

Adding [] in the column name should work. But I will suggest you to remove [] from all columns using -
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace("[", "", regex=True)
and
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace("]", "", regex=True)

Also note, the headers have spaces after the commas. These spaces will end up in the column names. You can get rid of them when reading with pd.read_csv(path, skipinitialspace=True)

But every time I try to run my program I get a KeyError Are we supposed to guess where this error happens?  Please update the question and add the full error traceback message.
